# Apache2: Directory paths while using mod_proxy

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, http-proxy

I am using a proxy in apache to redirect http requests to a different webserver on the same machine.

My sites-enabled/000-default.conf looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName server
    ProxyPreserverHost on
    ProxyPass /admin/ http://127.0.0.1:8080/mysite/admin/
</VirtualHost>
```

I want to add password authorization to the admin page via an external module (see http://icephoenix.us/linuxunix/apache-and-http-authentication-with-pam/), so I want a conf-enabled/admin.conf to look like this:

```
<IfModule mod_authnz_external.c>
    AddExternalAuth pwauth /usr/sbin/pwauth
    SetExternalAuthMethod pwauth pipe
</IfModule>

<Directory /admin/>
    AllowOverride None
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Admin page"
    AuthBasicProvider external
    AuthExternal pwauth
    Require valid-user
    Options FollowSymLinks Indexes    
</Directory>
```

When I try to access http://server/admin/, I can view it without needing a password. If I use

```
<Location /admin/>
```

instead of

```
<Directory /admin/>
```

a password is required.

Can someone tell me how I can set the  directive to point to the page where the password is required?

Comment: `<Directory /admin/> ` definitely is wrong, since the `Directory` command takes _an absolute path in the local file system_ as an argument. I doubt you are using a folder `admin` _at the root_ of your file system... You should indeed use `Location` here, since your setup is _not_ about a physical file system location from the front end servers point of view.

Comment: If I add the absolute path to admin (/var/www/html/admin/) I still don't get asked for a password.

Comment: You did not understand my full comment. The front end server does not know that it is _that_ physical folder that is accessed by the backend server. For the front end server only the location exists, everything else is remote and outside its control.

Comment: My apologies, now I understand. My reservation about using Location is borne from the apache website, which states that "It is important to never use <Location> when trying to restrict access to objects in the filesystem". In this case I am trying to restrict access to the admin pages, so I wanted to use <Directory>.

Comment: Read again what you yourself just wrote: "when trying to restrict access to objects in the filesystem". You _do not_ want to do that. You have to keep those two hosts or servers separate. The front end server does _not_ want to restrict access to objects in the file system, but to a remote service.